# Can I use "select *..." query with the bcp format nul option?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

When I run

```
bcp "select * from table where a='xyz'" format null -c -t, -f x.fmt -Sserver -T
```

it returns error "A valid table name is required for in,out or format options".  Does it now accept a query with the format option?  I tried the "out" option, it works with a query, but when import into a table, it complains on "Invalid character value for cast specification".  I seem to need the "format" bcp file, and I really don't want to dump the entire table but only a selection of it.  What's the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

After testing the "format nul" option of bcp, I concluded that the option only supports a dump of table with no queries.  However, I did solve my problems of "Invalid character value for cast specification" by specify "-r" with a specified terminating character (instead of the default \n).  That solved the problem of import

```
bcp <table> in outfile.bcp -c -t, -r? -S<server> -T
```

this works fine now.